# scala spark dataframe: explode a string column to multiple strings

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Any pointers on below?

input df: here `col1` is of type `string`

```
+----------------------------------+
|                              col1|
+----------------------------------+
|[{a:1,g:2},{b:3,h:4},{c:5,i:6}]   |
|[{d:7,j:8},{e:9,k:10},{f:11,l:12}]|
+----------------------------------+
```

expected output: (again `col1` is of type `string`)

```
+-------------+
|        col1 |
+-------------+
|  {a:1,g:2}  |
|  {b:3,h:4}  |
|  {c:5,i:6}  |
|  {d:7,j:8}  |
|  {e:9,k:10} |
|  {f:11,l:12}|
+-----+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Spark SQL explode function with an UDF :

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.createDataset(Seq("[{a},{b},{c}]","[{d},{e},{f}]")).toDF("col1")
df.show()

+-------------+
|         col1|
+-------------+
|[{a},{b},{c}]|
|[{d},{e},{f}]|
+-------------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val stringToSeq = udf{s: String => s.drop(1).dropRight(1).split(",")}
df.withColumn("col1", explode(stringToSeq($"col1"))).show()

+----+
|col1|
+----+
| {a}|
| {b}|
| {c}|
| {d}|
| {e}|
| {f}|
+----+
```

**Edit**: for you new input data, the custom UDF can evolve as above :

```
val stringToSeq = udf{s: String =>
  val extractor = "[^{]*:[^}]*".r
  extractor.findAllIn(s).map(m => s"{$m}").toSeq
}
```

new output :

```
+-----------+
|       col1|
+-----------+
|  {a:1,g:2}|
|  {b:3,h:4}|
|  {c:5,i:6}|
|  {d:7,j:8}|
| {e:9,k:10}|
|{f:11,l:12}|
+-----------+
```

Comment: Using native Spark functions, like a `regexp_replace` followed by a [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@split(str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), would most likely perform better than a UDF.

Comment: how would this change if this was a little different as: `val df = spark.createDataset(Seq("[{a:1,g:2},{b:3,h:4},{c:5,i:6}]","[{d:7,j:8},{e:9,k:10},{f:11,l:12}]")).toDF("col1")` to be more precise

Answer (score 2):

Spark provides a quite rich [trim](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#trim) function which can be used to remove the leading and the trailing chars, `[]` in your case. As @LeoC already mentioned the required functionality can be implemented through the build-in functions which will perform much better:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{trim, explode, split}

val df = Seq(
  ("[{a},{b},{c}]"),
  ("[{d},{e},{f}]")
).toDF("col1")

df.select(
  explode(
    split(
      trim($"col1", "[]"), ","))).show

// +---+
// |col|
// +---+
// |{a}|
// |{b}|
// |{c}|
// |{d}|
// |{e}|
// |{f}|
// +---+
```

**EDIT:**

For the new dataset the logic remains the same with the difference that you need to split with a different character other than `,`. You can achieve this using `regexp_replace` to replace `},` with `}|` in order to be able later to split with `|` instead of `,`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{trim, explode, split, regexp_replace}

val df = Seq(
  ("[{a:1,g:2},{b:3,h:4},{c:5,i:6}]"),
  ("[{d:7,j:8},{e:9,k:10},{f:11,l:12}]")
).toDF("col1")

df.select(
  explode(
    split(
      regexp_replace(trim($"col1", "[]"), "},", "}|"), // gives: {a:1,g:2}|{b:3,h:4}|{c:5,i:6}
    "\\|")
  )
).show(false)

// +-----------+
// |col        |
// +-----------+
// |{a:1,g:2}  |
// |{b:3,h:4}  |
// |{c:5,i:6}  |
// |{d:7,j:8}  |
// |{e:9,k:10} |
// |{f:11,l:12}|
// +-----------+
```

Note: with `split(..., "\\|")` we escape `|` which is a special regex character.

Comment: thanks, but apologies for the confusion, please see the updated example. the split by ',' is causing the issue still

Comment: note : This solution is valid for Spark 2.3.x or greater

Comment: That is valid @baitmbarek

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
val newDF = df.as[String].flatMap(line=>line.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(","))
newDF.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  {a}|
|  {b}|
|  {c}|
|  {d}|
|  {e}|
|  {f}|
+-----+
```

Just as a note, this process will name the output column as `value`, that you can easily rename it (if needed), using `select`, `withColumn`, etc.

Comment: thanks, but apologies for the confusion, please see the updated example. the split by ',' is causing the issue still

Comment: Try this: `df.select(trim('col1, "[]")).as[String].flatMap(record =>{
  val output = record.split("\\{").filter(_.size>0).map(rcd=> "{" + (if(rcd.trim().endsWith(",")) rcd.slice(0, rcd.size-1) else rcd) )
  output
}).show(truncate=false)`

Answer (score 1):

Finally what worked:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.createDataset(Seq("[{a:1,g:2},{b:3,h:4},{c:5,i:6}]","[{d:7,j:8},{e:9,k:10},{f:11,l:12}]")).toDF("col1")
df.show()

val toStr = udf((value : String) => value.split("},\\{").map(_.toString))
val addParanthesis = udf((value : String) => ("{" + value + "}"))
val removeParanthesis = udf((value : String) => (value.slice(2,value.length()-2)))

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df
.withColumn("col0", removeParanthesis(col("col1")))
.withColumn("col2", toStr(col("col0")))
.withColumn("col3", explode(col("col2")))
.withColumn("col4", addParanthesis(col("col3")))
.show()
```

output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+
|                col1|                col0|                col2|     col3|       col4|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+
|[{a:1,g:2},{b:3,h...|a:1,g:2},{b:3,h:4...|[a:1,g:2, b:3,h:4...|  a:1,g:2|  {a:1,g:2}|
|[{a:1,g:2},{b:3,h...|a:1,g:2},{b:3,h:4...|[a:1,g:2, b:3,h:4...|  b:3,h:4|  {b:3,h:4}|
|[{a:1,g:2},{b:3,h...|a:1,g:2},{b:3,h:4...|[a:1,g:2, b:3,h:4...|  c:5,i:6|  {c:5,i:6}|
|[{d:7,j:8},{e:9,k...|d:7,j:8},{e:9,k:1...|[d:7,j:8, e:9,k:1...|  d:7,j:8|  {d:7,j:8}|
|[{d:7,j:8},{e:9,k...|d:7,j:8},{e:9,k:1...|[d:7,j:8, e:9,k:1...| e:9,k:10| {e:9,k:10}|
|[{d:7,j:8},{e:9,k...|d:7,j:8},{e:9,k:1...|[d:7,j:8, e:9,k:1...|f:11,l:12|{f:11,l:12}|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: I think Too many udfs are not needed for a single string processing